# How do I access value outside the function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes, multer

I know that once defined in the function variables cannot be used outside the scope but I have a code that takes input as images and sends it to the database function. Below is my code, I am using NodeJS, Express and Multer.

```
router.post('/gymcreate',async(req,res) => {

  let userName = req.body.userName;
  let gymName = req.body.gymName;
  let location = req.body.location;
  let phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
  let priceRange = req.body.priceRange;

  let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('profile_pic');

  upload(req, res, function(err) {
      

      if (req.fileValidationError) {
          return res.send(req.fileValidationError);
      }
      else if (!req.file) {
          return res.send('Please select an image to upload');
      }
      else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
          return res.send(err);
      }
      else if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
      }

      let image = req.file.path;
  

  try{
    const creategym = await gymData.create(userName,gymName,location,phoneNumber,priceRange,image);
    
    if(creategym){
      res.status(200).redirect('/gyms')
      }
  else {
      res.status(500).render('gymbars/creategym', {title: "Error", error: 'Internal Server Error'})
      }
  }
  catch(e){
      res.sendStatus(500)
  }

      
      //res.send(`You have uploaded this image: <hr/><img src="${req.file.path}" width="500"><hr /><a href="./">Upload another image</a>`);
  });
  
  
})
```

The code has the route of the form which takes in inputs and also a file upload button. How do I access the image variable as I want access to the req.file.path outside the upload function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly do that. There's one workaround (that I wouldn't recommend)—declare a variable outside the function, then give it the value inside the function, like so:

```js
var someVar;
router.post("/somepath", (req, res) => {
    someVar = req.body.myAmazingVar;
    // ...
});
// use someVar here
```

However, as I mentioned, this isn't a good option. Besides, `someVar` will only be available when someone visits the page, and you don't know what `someVar` is associated with. An alternative way is to call a function and pass those values in as parameters, like:

```js
router.post("/somepath", (req, res) => {
    processData(req.body);
    // ...
});
function processData(data) {
    // do stuff, e.g.:
    var userName = data.userName, location = data.location;
    // or
    var { userName, location } = data;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how I'll use it here, but thanks for your input